# Unexplained trait bound no longer satisfied when modifying Axum handler body

Tags: asynchronous, rust, traits, rust-axum

Recently, I've started to learn Rust to build some simple web apps with Axum. However, I ended having an unexplained error while building the app, and I could not find the reason of it.

The failing to be built application code is the following:

```rust
use axum::{
    body::{Body, boxed, StreamBody},
    Extension,
    http::Request,
    response::Response,
    Router,
    routing::get,
};
use std::{
    path::PathBuf,
    sync::{Arc, RwLock},
};

type Cache = Arc<RwLock<PathBuf>>;

async fn handle_proxy(
    cache: Extension<Cache>,
    req: Request<Body>,
) -> Response {
    let cache = cache.read().unwrap();

    if let Some(object_key) = req.uri().path().rsplitn(2, '/').next() {
        // later the cache variable will be used to build the given path
        let file = tokio::fs::File::open("/tmp/testaroo").await;
        let buf_reader = tokio::io::BufReader::new(file.unwrap());
        let stream = tokio_util::io::ReaderStream::new(buf_reader);
        return Response::builder().body(boxed(StreamBody::new(stream))).unwrap();
    }

    // The function is not fully built here, there will be more code later, useless to demo the error.

    Response::builder().body(boxed("".to_string())).unwrap()
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let app = Router::new().route("/:key", get(handle_proxy));

    let addr = "0.0.0.0:8080";
    axum::Server::bind(&addr.parse().unwrap()).serve(app.into_make_service()).await.unwrap();
}
```

When the `let cache = cache.read().unwrap();` line is present (not commented above), the program is no longer building with the following error:

```bash
> cargo clippy
    Checking hello-rs-axum-failure v0.1.0 (/home/mycroft/tmp/broken-thing)
error[E0277]: the trait bound `fn(axum::Extension<std::sync::Arc<std::sync::RwLock<std::path::PathBuf>>>, axum::http::Request<axum::body::Body>) -> impl std::future::Future<Output = axum::http::Response<http_body::combinators::box_body::UnsyncBoxBody<axum::body::Bytes, axum::Error>>> {handle_proxy}: axum::handler::Handler<_, _, _>` is not satisfied
   --> src/main.rs:34:48
    |
34  |     let app = Router::new().route("/:key", get(handle_proxy));
    |                                            --- ^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `axum::handler::Handler<_, _, _>` is not implemented for fn item `fn(axum::Extension<std::sync::Arc<std::sync::RwLock<std::path::PathBuf>>>, axum::http::Request<axum::body::Body>) -> impl std::future::Future<Output = axum::http::Response<http_body::combinators::box_body::UnsyncBoxBody<axum::body::Bytes, axum::Error>>> {handle_proxy}`
    |                                            |
    |                                            required by a bound introduced by this call
    |
    = help: the following other types implement trait `axum::handler::Handler<T, S, B>`:
              <axum::handler::Layered<L, H, T, S, B, B2> as axum::handler::Handler<T, S, B2>>
              <axum::routing::MethodRouter<S, B> as axum::handler::Handler<(), S, B>>
note: required by a bound in `axum::routing::get`
   --> /home/mycroft/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/axum-0.6.18/src/routing/method_routing.rs:403:1
    |
403 | top_level_handler_fn!(get, GET);
    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `get`
    = note: this error originates in the macro `top_level_handler_fn` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
error: could not compile `hello-rs-axum-failure` due to previous error
```

I understand that adding the line is breaking something, but why? I found out limiting the scope of the declaration (ie: putting the instruction in its own scope and copying the underlying variable) will help, but I'd really like to know why the error is happening.

Comment: I think I figured out a bit more, by using the `debug_handler` macro. It seems like the cache is a `RwLockReadGuard` which removes the `Send` trait purposely, and the `await` instruction does not like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in the async handler function is holding onto the guard for the `cache` value in the scope.

As you discovered, this guard is not `Send`, so it can't be held across `await`s because the execution might continue on a different thread after resuming execution from an `await`.

Two possibilities to solve this:

1. Change the code so you don't hold the guard across an `await` boundary. (May or may not be possible or desirable.)
2. Use an async concurrency structure like [tokio::sync::RwLock](https://dtantsur.github.io/rust-openstack/tokio/sync/struct.RwLock.html) instead of the one in the standard library. These can be held across `await` boundaries.

Comment: Thanks for this answer (and your tine)! I've tested `tokio::sync::RwLock` and it fits correctly as well.